# Почему блок при применении `padding` увеличивает свои размеры?

Tags: css

В заглавии блоки `multi-accordion-title` и находящийся в нём `catalog-title` почему-то увеличивают с размер, когда применяется `padding` хотя их родительский блок шириной 240px. Как это исправить?
[image: изображение]

```js
$('.multi-accordion li > a').next().parent().addClass('has-children')

$('.multi-accordion .has-children > a').click(function(e) {
 var li = $(this).parent();
    li.parent('ul').find('.open').add(li).toggleClass('has-children open').children('ul');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.body {
  
}
.col-left-first {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 240px;
  margin-left: 240px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.multi-accordion-catalog {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.multi-accordion {
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #646464;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: none;
}
.multi-accordion ul {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
}
.multi-accordion li {
  list-style: none;
}
.multi-accordion > li  > a{
}
.multi-accordion > li  > ul  {
 padding-left: 8px;
}
.multi-accordion > li  > ul > li > ul  {
 padding-left: 8px;
}
.multi-accordion a, 
.multi-accordion a:link, 
.multi-accordion a:visited {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 24px 0 10px;
  color: #646464;
  position: relative;
}
.multi-accordion  a:hover {
}
.multi-accordion > a:only-child:link, 
.multi-accordion > a:only-child:visited {
  color: blue;
}
.multi-accordion > a:only-child:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  background: transparent;
}
.multi-accordion-title {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
.multi-accordion-title:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  top: 100%; left: -12px;  
  border-width: 0 12px 12px 0;
  border-color: transparent #cccccc transparent transparent;
}
.catalog-title {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  padding: 9px 0 0 10px;
  box-shadow: -4px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.catalog-title:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: -12px; 
  height: 100%;
  width: 12px;
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
}
.catalog-title:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 40px 40px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #e1e1e1;
}
.has-children,
.open {
  position: relative;
}
.has-children > a:before ,
.open > a:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  top: 8px;
  right: 4px;
}
.has-children > a:before {
  background: url(https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ios-7-icons/50/down4-16.png) no-repeat;
}
.open > a:before {
  background: url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/mayssam/512/Top_2-16.png) no-repeat;
}
.multi-accordion .open  > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-left-first">
    <div class="multi-accordion-catalog">
        <div class="multi-accordion-title">
            <dt class="catalog-title">Каталог</dt>
        </div>
        <ul class="multi-accordion">
            <li>
                <a href="http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1a.html">Напольное покрытие</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1a/category-level2a.html">Паркетная доска</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Category 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Category 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ламинат</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Пробковые покрытия</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Аксессуары</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1b.html">Тёплый пол</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1a/category-level2a.html">Инфакрасная плёнка</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Category 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Category 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Нагревательные маты</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="#">Термостаты</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Освещение</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Двери</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

По умолчанию значение `padding` не включается в высоту и ширину блока. Либо отнимайте от размеров высоты и ширины значения `padding`, либо задавайте целевому блоку свойство `box-sizing:border-box;`, которое включит внутренние отступы и границы в значения ширины и высоты элемента

```
.multi-accordion-title {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    ...
}
```